# I want to acces an input field inside javascript function whose id is generated using php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to set value calculated inside javascript function to a input field whose id is generated using php code.

assigning php code to variable inside javascript function and then assign using that variable to set value of input feld.

```
<td> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $cartr['price'] * $value['quantity']; ?>" id="<?php echo $pricefield; ?>" readonly></td>

    function decrement(qty, priceid) {
            if (document.getElementById(qty).value >= 2) {
                var x=document.getElementById(qty).value;
                x--;
                document.getElementById(qty).value = x;
                var y = document.getElementById(priceid).value;
                var sum = x * y;
                var fieldname = "<?php echo $pricefield; ?>";
                document.getElementById(fieldname).value = sum;
            }else{
                 alert("Quantity cannot be less than 1");
            }
        }
```

Comment: what you are gettingnow?

Comment: How do you call `decrement()`?

Comment: @SanjunDev I get "string literal contains an unescaped line break" error in console and in detailed "<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: pricefield in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/final/cart.php</b>"

Comment: @Barmar I have defined it in head tag and call it passing quantity and price where price is hidden type.

Comment: where is your <script> tag? is you missed it or not added here?

Comment: script tag is inside head tag above all these code

Comment: It looks like the code should work. What problem are you having? But I don't understand why you need to generate the ID dynamically in the first place. Just hard-code a specific ID into both the HTML and the function.

Comment: @Barmar i wont be knowing the number of ids required and i want to calculate total price which i get dynamically based on the product stored inside td which has been assigned inside it dynamically.

Comment: The function can only have one `$pricefield` in it, which is assigned by the PHP script, not dynamically on the client.

Comment: how can i dynamically assign it php field whose id is also dynamically assigned.

Comment: don't use `id` attributes if the content is being generated dynamicaly - there are much cleaner methods of processing the DOM than that. ie: querySelectorAll

Comment: @RamRaider still i am having issue accessing the column dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly put together a demo of how you might do what you want based upon my interpretation of the snippets of code provided ( it was similar to another question I saw earlier today ) ~ copy all and save as a php file to run. Essentially you want to separate PHP and the Javascript completely - also remove any inline event handlers too. By using `querySelectorAll` and `sibling selectors` you can traverse the DOM very easily to identify elements of interest and assign listeners. If you use `ID` attributes and then rely upon `document.getElementById` you limit yourself somewhat as you must keep track of IDs - which of course must be unique. It used to be the case that an ID attribute could not simply be an integer - that was relaxed with the introduction of `HTML5`- but it is, imo, still not good practise to use integers for IDs.

The following might not fully satisfy your requirements but it will give a good idea how you can access elements within the DOM and trigger functions accordingly. Good luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Dynamic elements Price Increment & Decrement</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('td > input[ type="button" ]') ).forEach( input=>{
                    input.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        let qty=this.parentNode.querySelector('input[name="qty[]"]');
                        let price=this.parentNode.querySelector('input[name="price[]"]');
                        let sum=this.parentNode.querySelector('input[name="sum[]"]');

                        switch( this.dataset.dir ){
                            case 'increment':
                                qty.value++;
                            break;
                            case 'decrement':
                                if( qty.value > 1 ) qty.value--;
                                else {
                                    alert( 'Quantity cannot be less than 1' );
                                }
                            break;
                        }
                        sum.value=qty.value * price.value;
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            table{width:100%;}
            tr{width:100%;}
            td{display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center;align-content:center;}
            [type='button']{ width:2rem; height:2rem; text-align:center; font-size:1rem; clear:none; cursor:pointer; margin:0.25rem; }
            [type='text']{ height:2rem; margin:0.25rem;  text-align:center;  }
            td *{ display:inline-block; }
            label{width:20%;}
            label > input{float:right}
            label:before{content:attr(data-label)}
            [readonly]{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <?php
                    for( $i=1; $i <=10; $i++ ){

                        $qty=mt_rand(1,10);
                        $price=mt_rand(1,100);

                        printf('
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" data-dir="decrement" value="-" />

                                <label data-label="Quantity" for="qty"><input type="number" name="qty[]" value="%d" min=1 /></label>
                                <label data-label="Price" for="price"><input type="number" name="price[]" value="%d" min=1 readonly /></label>
                                <label data-label="Total" for="sum"><input type="number" name="sum[]" value="%d" readonly /></label>

                                <input type="button" data-dir="increment" value="+" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>',
                        $qty,
                        $price,
                        $qty * $price );
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```